# Colon after struct name with data type

Tags: c++11

While reading some boost library source code I encountered this part

```
template< class Value = double >
struct rk4_coefficients_a3 : boost::array< Value , 3 >
{
    rk4_coefficients_a3( void )
        {
    (*this)[0] = static_cast<Value>(0);
    (*this)[1] = static_cast<Value>(0);
    (*this)[2] = static_cast<Value>(1);
        }
};
```

What does the colon (:) mean after struct name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `struct` is just the same thing as a `class`, just with default visibility of `public` for its members and ancestors.  So a `struct` can inherit from another `class`/`struct`. In your example, `rk4_coefficients_a3` inherits from `boost::array< Value , 3 >` using `public` inheritance.